# Resteasy Client with SSL client authentication does not work

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, curl, https

I have p12 client certificate. I have host with SSL certificate which is signed by RapidSSL and which added my p12 cert for client authentication. I use Resteasy Client to access to this host. The code below which I use to connect:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("my_cert.p12"), keyPass.toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "my_pass".toCharArray())
        .build();
ResteasyClientBuilder clientBuilder = (ResteasyClientBuilder) ResteasyClientBuilder.newBuilder();
clientBuilder.sslContext(sslContext);
Client client = clientBuilder.build();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://client_auth.somehost.com/wrong/path");
Response response = webTarget.request().get();
Assert.assertEquals(404, response.getStatus());
```

No exception, no other errors. It just returns 403 for any URLs.

To check, that my cert.p12 is correct I've tried to connect using curl.

1. convert p12 to pem

   openssl pkcs12 -in my_cert.p12 -out my_cert.pem -clcerts
2. try to connect using curl

   curl -v -1 --cert my_cert.pem:my_pass "https://client_auth.somehost.com/wrong/path"

the result:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

3. download through browser host Certificate and specify it as trusted

   curl -v -1 --cert my_cert.pem:my_pass --cacert public_CA.crt "https://client_auth.somehost.com/wrong/path"

the result was:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

So, it means that my_cert is OK. So why it does not work from the java code?

Java version "1.8.0_31" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

### Update

I've rewrote code to java native SSL, and got absolutely the same result.
Also, I found information, that host based on apache with openSSL on CentOS.